# Unexpected output when saving/loading dictionary to/from json

Tags: python, json

Python 2.7.6 on windows 7
The code I use:

```
import json

settings = {
    "vo" : "direct3d",
    "ao" : "dsound",
    "volume" : "100",
    "priority" : "abovenormal"}

json.dump(settings, open('settings.json', 'w'))
settings = json.load(open('settings.json', 'r'))

print settings
```

In settings.json I get:

```
{"volume": "100", "priority": "abovenormal", "ao": "dsound", "vo": "direct3d"}
```

At the end console outputs:

```
{u'volume': u'100', u'priority': u'abovenormal', u'ao': u'dsound', u'vo': u'direct3d'}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong; that's the exact output you should be expecting.

JSON deals exclusively with Unicode strings; the `u''` strings are such Unicode values. If all your strings contain characters within the ASCII range, you'll not notice any difference when handling these.

In other words, using mixing regular (byte) strings with these values will work, Python will transparently encode and decode between the two types. You'll only notice problems when your text contains characters that fall outside of the ASCII range. Think accented characters, or symbols, or asian scripts, for example. In that case you should learn how to use Unicode properly, see the [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks, I didnt check if I could use them after. I was just stuck at the odd, for me, output

Answer (score 1):

You're doing nothing wrong. `json.load` will convert everything to unicode, which is what the `u` stands for.

This should not affect the use of that dictionary, for example:

```
>>> result = {u'volume': u'100', u'priority': u'abovenormal', u'ao': u'dsound',
u'vo': u'direct3d'}
>>> result['volume']
u'100'
```

If it turns out to be a problem, you can always use [`simplejson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) which does not force the unicode. Or you can write a converter function and hook it to the [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load)-function as the `object_hook` argument.

Here's the object_hook-example [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders):

```
>>> import json
>>> def as_complex(dct):
...     if '__complex__' in dct:
...         return complex(dct['real'], dct['imag'])
...     return dct
...
>>> json.loads('{"__complex__": true, "real": 1, "imag": 2}',
...     object_hook=as_complex)
(1+2j)
>>> import decimal
>>> json.loads('1.1', parse_float=decimal.Decimal)
Decimal('1.1')
```